# How to know who the SMS Participants are in a Twilio Conversation?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-conversations

I am using the conversations API and I can add SMS participants to a conversation via my Twilio Number. Both parties can communicate through their devices via Twilio Conversations. Is there a way to show who's talking in the SMS message from Twilio Conversations?

Ie:

```
"Tim says: Help me."
"Support says: This is a support ticket #33492"
"Level 2 Support says: I'll take it from here"
```

I researched the API and Webhooks to intercept the SMS inbound but it seems Conversations API doesn't allow this. I thought I could block the inbound message and append the sender's identity to the msg since all we have are their cellphone number and attributes of the participant, which contains the name and email.

Update: Trying pre-webhooks first.  Webhooks allow me to intercept, but do not let me change the content. Also looks like delay on a webhook will be ignored and the SMS is delivered.